# Suddenly VOLTE not working on my moto g4 plus

Tags: motorola-moto-g, voice-over-lte

I was using VOLTE services (from reliance jio in India) seamlessly since November 2016, but since June 2017 it suddenlt stopped working. I get an error "Unable to place call. Please try another method" while trying to make a call. I am able to access the internet and make/recieve calls from the Jio 4G Voice app.

**UPDATES:**

- I have enabled "enhanced 4G LTE mode"
- Did a factory reset
- My jio connection is on and working. Also, I can place/receive calls from the `Jio4GVioce` app which means the service is working fine.

Comment: Have you recharged your JIO number? Have you switched on mobile data for JIO and turned on volte in sim settings?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal yes mobile data is on. What do you mean by *turned on volte in sim settings*?

Comment: Follow the below answer to turn on volte in your phone. Have you recharged your jio number? May be service is disconnected.

Comment: you can check answer here [JIO VoLTE is not working with Moto G5 plus](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225926/281099)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings/Wireless and networks/...More/Cellular networks** and check whether **Enhanced 4G LTE mode** is enabled. Somebody (you) might have turned it off accidentally.

Comment: yes, its enabled

Comment: What's the result?

Comment: Same. It was enabled the whole time

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem

Steps:

- I tried to wipe partition, does not worked for VOLTE.
- Removed the JIO SIM from slot 1 and inserted on slot 2.
- then removed the JIO sim from slot 2 and inserted BSNL SIM in slot 1, BSNL works.
  Then remove the BSNL SIM & insert JIO SIM in slot 1.

Now VOLTE is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to **boot into safe mode** and then toggle Volte on and check if it works there. 
 
**To (re)boot into safe mode:** 
Press the Power key, then tap and hold on Power off, and then tap OK when Reboot to safe mode The Moto G4 will reboot and you should see Safe Mode in the bottom-left corner.