# JIO VoLTE is not working with Moto G5 plus

Tags: 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g

I am trying from so many days to enable VoLTE on MOTO G5 PLUS but VoLTE is not working in any of the SIM slots. The current Android version is Nougat.

Can somebody help me how can I enable VoLTE option on my phone? It is really frustrating that I need to use some third party app to make a call on 4G network.

Comment: Did it worked previously or it never worked from beginning and make sure that enhanced 4g LTE mode is turned on, even i had this issue twice in past and it was solved automatically after few days

Answer (score 1):

This could pe possible if *VoLTE or HD calling* is not enabled under sim card settings.
Make sure you have turned it on.

It might be possible that your current network didn't working properly on VoLTE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the **Enhanced 4G LTE Mode** option in the Mobile Network option in the Settings is enabled? If it is not enabled, then you need to check this option, then it will work fine.

If you do not find an option such as Enhanced VoLTE, then try to change the SIM card to a different slot (it will be better if Jio SIM is in the first slot) and restart the phone and check again if such an option appears. If you do not find the option again, then try to clear the cache partition the method is seen here in the link [here](https://support.motorola.com/us/en/solution/MS111301).

If you still do not find any solution, then you can finally try the solution below. First, you need to have ADB drivers installed on your PC and you need to enable developer options and debug mode on the phone. Then try using the following commands as below in command prompt (cmd if you using Windows system) or Terminal (if you are using Ubuntu)

1. `adb reboot bootloader` (useful to start bootloader of the phone)
2. `fastboot erase modemst1`
3. `fastboot erase modemst2`
4. Press the lock key to start the phone from bootloader mode

Comment: You haven't mentioned how to reflash those partitions after erasing.

Comment: @Gokul NC as the command only remove EFS partition in the phone and on reboot the phone the EFS partition will automatically generate so I didn't need to reflash it for this phone but still for more information you can read one good article here https://nerdschalk.com/fix-empty-imei-corrupted-efs-no-sim-unknown-baseband-wifibluetooth-issues-restoring-twrp-backup/